# How to register icon images for contents of TreeViewer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jface

I have a tree which is dynamic (where i can add and remove tree objects). And i want a specific icon to be displayed for a specific object.

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a label provider with a TreeViewer. For tree viewer this can be either [`ILabelProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ILabelProvider.html) (single column) or [`ITableLabelProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ITableLabelProvider.html) (for multiple columns). Return the image in `getImage()`/`getColumnImage()` method.